# Static Physics body still moving with contact

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Hello I have a physics body created within sprite kit editor, here are the settings I've set for it:

[image]

The problem is, it isn't acting "static". If another physics body bumps into it "weirdly" (for lack of a better description) it often glitches, flying all over the screen, or when I had it pinned, rotating around the pinned location. -Shouldn't this act static and *never* move, unless it is explicitly moved in code? I need it to have an alpha mask physics body and stand completely still (it is the ground in my scene).

Comment: Everything looks good at first glance. Is it possible it is actually the parent node that is being affected by physics?

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply. I am adding this node to an empty SKNode "worldNode" that I am using for a scrolling effect. It doesn't have a physics body so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: If I have one or more physics bodies acting against each other on the ground (the static physics body I referenced in my question) the acting bodies glitch and the ground eventually "gives" and rotates or goes flying.

Comment: From my understanding bit-masks should have nothing to do with the behavior of a static physics bodies movement, correct? Bit-masks determine which bodies act on each other and the contact delegate methods.

Comment: To my understand yes and what I have done in the past that is the case. What concerns me is you keep saying "glitches" making it sound like it is more than just a physics thing. It almost sounds like the "glitch" is unrelated to the ground, but when it does happen it affects the ground. Is that the case?

Comment: That's a distinct possibility - but regardless of other glitches a static body should never move - and it is. I know one thing I'm doing is moving sprites directly using `self.position = CGPointMake()` and this is generally considered "glitchier" than moving a physics body using impulses.

Comment: Ok, I seemed to have fixed it - oddly enough, I had created a pointer to the node in the sks file `SKNode *ground = (SKNode *)[self childNodeWithName:@"ground"];` and then I explicitly declared the node as `ground.physicsBody.dynamic=NO;` - Deleting this declaration fixed the problem - I don't know why removing this worked but it did. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem. Sometimes hashing things out with someone helps a ton. Although that fixes the issue for now I agree that shouldn't change it. Bust of luck and hopefully some day all of it will make sense and know why it fixes it :)