# Static bodies still moving

Tags: sprite-kit

this may be a duplicate of
[Static Physics body still moving with contact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28800222/static-physics-body-still-moving-with-contact)

but I have not the reputation to add a comment.
My problem is with collisions and static bodies. I'm working on a little game and I have a player, so configured (from sks file):

```
player = worldNode.childNodeWithName("player") as! SKSpriteNode
    let playerBodyTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "player_physicBody_mask")
    player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: playerBodyTexture, size: CGSizeMake(player.size.width, player.size.height))
    player.physicsBody!.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
    player.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.player
    player.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ground | PhysicsCategory.enemies
    player.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.enemies
    player.physicsBody!.restitution = 0
    player.physicsBody!.friction = 0
    player.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false}
```

an enemy:

```
worldNode.enumerateChildNodesWithName("enemy") { node, _ in
        let enemy = node as! SKSpriteNode
        enemy.name = "enemy"
        enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 17)
        enemy.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
        enemy.physicsBody!.mass = 0.4
        enemy.physicsBody!.restitution = 0
        enemy.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.enemies
        enemy.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ground | PhysicsCategory.player
        enemy.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.player}
```

and I have the platfrom brick, so configured:

```
worldNode.enumerateChildNodesWithName("fixedBlock") { node, _ in
        let fixedBlock = node as! SKSpriteNode
        fixedBlock.name = "fixedBlock"
        let fixedBlockBodyTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "tripleBlocks_physicBody_mask")
        fixedBlock.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: fixedBlockBodyTexture, size: CGSizeMake(fixedBlock.size.width, fixedBlock.size.height))
        fixedBlock.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ground
        fixedBlock.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.player | PhysicsCategory.enemies
        fixedBlock.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = 0
        fixedBlock.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
        fixedBlock.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
        fixedBlock.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false
        fixedBlock.physicsBody!.pinned = false
        fixedBlock.physicsBody!.friction = 0.3
        fixedBlock.physicsBody!.restitution = 0}
```

When the player jumps on the enemies, he has an impulse (like Super Mario :-)), so I have this:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let collision: UInt32 = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask
    if collision == PhysicsCategory.player | PhysicsCategory.enemies {
           self.player.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 500))}}
```

Ok...  sometimes, often, when the player jumps on enemy, the impulse appens correctly, but the ground tile moves down, also if its dynamic propriety is set on false. I tried to apply a JointFixed on the ground tile but when it is pushed down, its physic body "glitch"; I tried to print the physicsBody velocity propierty of the ground tile and when the problem occours, the velocity's dx vector is >100, but should static bodies not be affected by forces?
Any idea?

Many thanks

Comment: Are you using Tiled for your map?

Comment: No, I'm using the Xcode's built in scene editor (sks file)

Comment: I had (am) having a similar issue with nodes moving unexpectedly on rare occasions. Try using SKConstraint on your floor tiles to lock them into place.

Comment: I tried, but if the block is fixed with joint (fixed, pin, spring) when the problem occurs, it "glitchs", "vibrates" because tis velocity property goes at >100... I tried also with the constraint, in this case, when the problem happens, the sprite's texture rest in place, because of the constraint, but its physicBody goes down...